# Cohen-Macaulay and regular rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, cohen-macaulay

I know this is a simple question but to make sure...:

> $A$ is a commutative ring which is Cohen-Macaulay and for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ in $A$ we have $\dim A_{\mathfrak{m}}=\dim A$. Is then $A$ regular?

This seems wrong... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reduced noetherian ring of dimension $1$ is Cohen-Macaulay, but they are not regular in general.

Example: $A=\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$.

Answer (score 2):

For instance, there are local CM rings that aren't regular.

Comment: I know but I was wondering when is a local CM ring regular?

Comment: @CSA: Then perhaps that is the question that you should ask!